# Can Netbeans run projects in specific VMs?

Tags: netbeans

I have a 64-bit Java 7 JDK installed on my Win7 system.

One of the projects I'm working on, however, needs to call some ancient C DLLs (via JNI) for which I only have 32-bit versions. If I try to run this in the 64-bit JVM I get the error "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform" - no biggie, just run it using a 32-bit JRE that I have installed for precisely this reason.

However, I'm trying to migrate to using NetBeans 7.2 for development work (from using TextPad, ant, javac) and NetBeans is selecting the 64-bit JRE if I click "Run" from within the IDE.

Is there a way of telling NetBeans to select a different JRE for this one project? (The rest of the things I'm working on are pure-Java, so no need to change the JRE for those).

Answer (score 4):

Under Tools -> Java Platforms you need to "register" the 32bit JDK/JRE.

Then in your Project Properties under "Libraries" select that JDK.

Comment: I did try to register my 32-bit JRE, but it looks like you can only register a JDK (not a JRE) under Tools -> Java Platforms, and that would switch to building with the 32-bit JDK. I appreciate that shouldn't really be an issue, so it looks like I'm going to have to go ahead and install another full JDK (which might keep getting deleted due to the annoying system policies here)

Comment: @RobGilliam: correct. For a Java project NetBeans needs a JDK: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre but you don't need to "install" the JDK. You can e.g. copy it from another PC and put it anywhere on your PC.