# The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch Error

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

i got this error:

> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver
>   and Application

while trying to connect to the database using NetBeans and Java Programming Language

I am using Microsoft Access 2010 and my system running at 64bit Windows 7.

How do i solve this problem? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

That message appears under the following circumstances:

- you have the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") installed,
- you create an ODBC DSN for your database connection, and
- your Java code is running in a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) whose "bit-ness" is different than that of the installed version of ACE.

For example,

1. you could have the 32-bit version of ACE installed and be trying to connect from Java code running in a 64-bit JVM, or
2. you could have the 64-bit version of ACE installed and be trying to connect from Java code running in a 32-bit JVM.

If you *really* want to use the JDBC-ODBC Bridge then the solution is to either switch to the "other" version of ACE (i.e., switch from 32-bit to 64-bit or vice versa), or have your Java code run under a JVM with the same "bit-ness" as the installed version of ACE.

(Note that if you have Office installed then "switching to 64-bit ACE" really means "switching to 64-bit Office". You can't "mix and match" 32-bit and 64-bit Office components.)

However, now that the JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed from Java 8 you should consider using the [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver instead. It is a pure Java implementation that does not use Access ODBC to manipulate the database, so it works under both 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs on all platforms that run Java (i.e., not just Windows). For more details, see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Comment: Before i install Access Database Engine, the ODBC Administrator cannot add the Microsoft Database Engine in System DSN tab and under add selection and i already tried to download Access Database Engine 64 bit (2010), but the installer says that i cannot install it, because Microsoft Office 2010. So i decided to install Access Database Engine 32 bit (2010) and the Microsoft Database Engine works properly and i can add that under add selection in System DSN. But when i run through NetBeans (Java), i am getting that error

Comment: @Kaoru Okay, so you need to download and install the 32-bit JDK (the page [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/develop.xml) will lead you to it), and then you need to tell NetBeans to use the 32-bit Platform for that specific project (more information in another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17491277/2144390)).